# How to check for hyperlinks in the contents of a message (through Discord.py preferably)

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to be able to detect when a discord user sends a URL link, whether it be a video, website, or discord invite, and to save the link, are there any pre-existing libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is my favourite solution for this.

```
    def _match_url(url):
        regex = re.compile(
            "(([\w]+:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?"
        )
        if regex.match(url):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if regex.match(url):
            return True
        else:
            return False` be simplified to `return regex.match(url)` ?